# adb command not found even after setting path in mac

Tags: android, bash, macos, terminal

I have set following path in my `bash_profile` file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/viki-donor/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/26.0.2:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

I saved it and ran the command `source ~/.bash_profile`. If I type `adb` the command is running successfully. But after sometime. If I run the same command `adb` its not able to recognize the command and I get `command not found` error. I again run `source ~/.bash_profile` and it starts working fine. Why do I have to run `source ~/.bash_profile` again and again ?

Comment: I think that `~/.bash_profile` is only run for login shells, you should add these settings to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Added in that as well. I have kept in both the places `bash_profile` and `bashrc_profile` Same problem @ArkadiuszDrabczyk

Comment: Is the subsequent errors in the same shell instance that you sourced it earlier? If so, something else are messing with the environment, what does `echo $PATH` say when it is broken and what might set it to that value?

Comment: After adding the PATH to bash_profile I closed the terminal. I ran echo $PATH and its giving me correct value. But after sometime when I leave the system and open a new terminal instance I get command not found error. I have to source ~/.bash_profile again to get the PATH working fine. @GertvandenBerg

Comment: @XoXo: environment variables like `$PATH` applies for a process (and is kept in child processes). This means that it needs to be applied on all subsequent shells (`.bash_profile` for login shells, `.bashrc` for non-login shells)... Posting your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files might help

Comment: @XoXo: The bashrc file is `~/.bashrc` NOT `~/.bashrc_profile` see the FILES section in [bash's man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This only applies if you are using bash as your shell. Other shells have other scripts.

To ensure that the settings are loaded in non-login shells, you should add it to the `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

(It often makes sense to have this in your `.bash_profile`):

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

This means that your bashrc is always loaded, whether it is a login shell or not.

For settings that should apply to all users, you can usually create a `.sh` file in `/etc/profile.d/` with the settings or edit `/etc/bashrc` (or `/etc/bash.bashrc` in some cases) (and `/etc/profile`)

(There are often better methods to set environment variables, like `/etc/environment` on Linux boxes using `pam_env`)

Comment: great answer. Thanks